# Identify type of switch

Tags: electrical, switch

Can anyone identify the type of switch this is? There are 4 connectors at the bottom and 3 at the top.

[image]

I've already purchased a 2 gang 2 way switch which turned out to be the wrong one (it only has 2 connectors at the top).

I'm in the UK if terminology differs from other countries.

Comment: what is the switch connected to?

Comment: It's connected to two lights. I've done a diagram, it's the unit in the middle I'm trying to replace. http://i.imgur.com/4ox1r.jpg

Comment: that's actually two switches, then. Two two-way switches. Not sure about the UK, but in the US it's not recommended to use the push-connectors (use the screw terminals instead).

Comment: The push connectors are fine in the US IF your house has the proper gauge wire; houses are generally either 12AWG or 14AWG, and the push connectors on a switch will only work with one or the other. Too small and it slides right out (and wil arc and can cause a fire), too big and it might not go in and it DEFINITELY won't come out properly.

Comment: I can't tell from the pics or your diagram, but looks like you may have 1) 3-way  and a separate 4-way.  Don't see that type of ganging of switches here in the US.

Comment: Turn off the power, disconnect the switch (the one you want to replace), take the switch with you to the hardware store.  I'm sure somebody at the store will be able to help you find the correct switch, if not at least you'll have something to compare to while shopping.

Answer (score 4):

What you have is a four way switch and a three way switch. The three way is the one with the three wires, the four way is the one with four wires. Take note of the 'point' wire on the three way if you intend to replace it, you should find some marking on the back of the switch that indicates which leg that is.

As said in comments, it's unusual to see those in the US, but they are common in Europe and Asia. [Akari](http://www.akari.com.ph/16-wiring-devices-and-electrical) makes an almost identical line of 'slim and stackable' wiring devices, except slightly smaller, if you're looking for an approved / listed replacement.